# Прочитать HTML таблицу с WEB страницы и нарисовать гистограмму (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, визуализация

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

f = urlopen("http://wiki.stat.ucla.edu/socr/index.php/SOCR_Data_Dinov_020108_HeightsWeights")
Страница = f.read().decode("UTF-8")
f.close()
print(Страница)
```

Вопрос в том, как достать с HTML сайта таблицу и вывести на экран при помощи `matplotlib`.

Comment: а в каком виде вы хотите вывести на экран данную таблицу? Что будет по оси `X` и что по `Y`?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url='http://wiki.stat.ucla.edu/socr/index.php/SOCR_Data_Dinov_020108_HeightsWeights'
# parse all HTML tables into a list of DataFrames
# and select the second (index==1) element (DF)
df = pd.read_html(url)[1]
# set column names with values from the first row
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
# get rid of first row (column names have already been set)
df = df.iloc[1:]
# cast data types to numeric ones
df[['Height(Inches)', 'Weight(Pounds)']] = df[['Height(Inches)', 'Weight(Pounds)']].astype('float16')

# set fancier matplotlib style    
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
# plot scatter plot
df.plot.scatter(x='Height(Inches)',y='Weight(Pounds)', s=20)
plt.show()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Гистограмма распределения веса:

```
# plot a histogram for the `Weight(Pounds)` column
df[['Weight(Pounds)']].plot.hist(width=6, alpha=0.6)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень благодарен, а только с помощью модуля pandas можно ? Так как pandas не изучал, толком не знаю о ней.

Comment: @VladPaskevits, я уверен, что это можно сделать многими различными способами. Просто я использую Pandas, т.к. это позволяет мне писать короткий, эффективный (часто на порядки быстрее по сравнению с обычным "Vanilla Python")  и понятный код. Кстати, у StackOverflow [есть отличная возможность сказать спасибо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;-)

Comment: Я конечно не до конца понимаю код, не могли бы вы рассказать о нем по больше ? Был бы очень благодарен .

Comment: @VladPaskevits, добавил комментарии в код